# Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[login] : Ngx-translate

Tags: ionic3, ngx-translate

I am using [ngx-translate, The internationalization (i18n) library for Angular](https://github.com/ngx-translate/core) to achieve i18n in my ionic application

**Below is my code which works fine and i am able to achieve i18n**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPageModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { LoginPage } from './login';
import { TranslateLoader, TranslateModule } from "@ngx-translate/core";
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";
import { PPMTranslateLoader } from "../../shared/PPMTranslateLoader";

export function createTranslateLoader(http: HttpClient) {
    return new PPMTranslateLoader(http, [{prefix: './assets/i18n/', 
                                          suffix: 'login.json'}]);
}

@NgModule({
    declarations: [LoginPage],
    imports: [
        IonicPageModule.forChild(LoginPage),
        // Required to change translation language.
        TranslateModule.forChild({
            loader: {
                provide: TranslateLoader,
                useFactory: (createTranslateLoader),
                deps: [HttpClient]
            }
        })
    ],
    providers: [HttpClient]
})
export class LoginPageModule {
}
```

But I don't want to have createTranslateLoader method in every module of my application hence thought of moving this to my CustomLoader as the static method and just pass the file name(which keep on changing dynamically) as the part of deps array in TranslateModule.forChild's configuration object .

Something like this

```
 TranslateModule.forChild({
            loader: {
                provide: TranslateLoader,
                useFactory: (PPMTranslateLoader.createTranslateLoader), // static factory 
                deps: [HttpClient, LoginPageModule.staticFileName]
                                       /\
                                       ||
                                       ||
                                       ||
      ( I want to pass this dynamically in every module where i need i18n)
  }
})
```

But using this configuration I ended up getting the below error

```
Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[login]: 
                                                                     /\
                                                                     ||
                                                                     ||
                                                                     ||

            (This staticFileName is getting resolved but it's not being injected)
```

Can someone suggest what is the correct way of achieving it?